# Does Google's Geocoding API produce any quality code like Mapquest API generating the quality code for the addresses?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-geocoding-api, geocode, mapquest

This is the JSON response of mapquest API which has this attribute below:

```
{
...
"geocodeQualityCode": "A5XAX"
...

}
```

likewise is there any implementation provided by Google API?

Answer (score 0):

Google's Geocoding API does not provide a `geocodeQualityCode` attribute.

However it does return some information on the quality of the results in the [following fields](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#Results):

> `geometry.location_type`: The following values are currently supported:
>
> > `"ROOFTOP"` indicates that the returned result
> >     is a precise geocode for which we have location information accurate
> >     down to street address precision.
> >
> > `"RANGE_INTERPOLATED"` indicates that the returned result reflects an approximation (usually on a road) interpolated between two precise points (such as intersections).
> >
> > `"GEOMETRIC_CENTER"` indicates that the returned result is the geometric
> >     center of a result such as a polyline (for example, a street) or
> >     polygon (region).
> >
> > `"APPROXIMATE"` indicates that the returned result is approximate.
>
> `partial_match` indicates that the geocoder did not return an exact match for the original request, though it was able to match part of the requested address.

Hope you find this helpful.